# CSS: absolute position and relative position

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I am a bit noob in CSS and just started designing a website. What's happening is i am trying to put a logo div on my header div with background color blue. Everything is just fine but when i set the position of child div (logo div) the blue color disappear.

style.css

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

#header {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" >
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you using absolute position? absolute position can not contain anything inside when has not height and width.

Comment: but absolute div contains an image and it already has height and width of its own..

Comment: Please use UTF-8, which [should only be declared in html and not in CSS](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset)

Comment: decrease the size of the logo

Comment: why do you need `position:absolute`? it might not be the best practice for your specific situation.

Comment: actually someone suggested me that parent div should be relative and child div should be absolute so that it could be more flexible when accessing on different screen size ... @Aziz

Comment: It certainly helps in some cases, like when you want to make sure an element STICKS to the side of screen/viewport for example but in general, it is not needed and can create more issues if you do not understand how the CSS layout and box model work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you changed the pic position to `absolute` it jumped out of the header, then your `div` area became equal to zero. So now you need to set a size for it.

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#header {
  background:skyblue;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:190px;
  text-align:center;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Goy7oBy.gif" style="max-height:190px">
</div>
<h2 style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:white;line-height:190px;margin:0px">TITLE</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height of your header. This is because absolute div is kind of "outside" of the header therefor header's height is became 0.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you did not mention any height for the header div and when I tried your code by removing the logo div also I have not seen any blue color, Then I realized the height is not mentioned.

```
 height: Xpx;/* This works */
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height of the #header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"><title>Insert title here</title>
<style type = "text/css">
#header {
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 500px;
}

#logo {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" >
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="me.png">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```